# calling web service from login module n websphere

Tags: web-services, websphere, websphere-7, jaas

I have a  websphere login module which calls a web service to get some information while authenticating. There is a different web service URL for different environments. Can anyone suggest the best way of deploying this so I dont have to redeploy the code between environments.

I have added the wsdl's to the META-INF folder in my deployed jar file. And set custom properties for the login module so I can determine which wsdl file to get.

However when I search for the wsdl it does not correctly load it as it throws a null pointer after intialisation.

```
[6/26/14 15:23:48:786 BST] 00000048 SystemOut     O Debug: com.xxx.login.module.xxxCustomLoginModule
[6/26/14 15:23:48:786 BST] 00000048 SystemOut     O     got wsdl Url file:/usr/websphere7/ndb70SU3_B
117/lib/ext/xxxCustomLoginModule.jar!/META-INF/wsdl/my-pre.wsdl
```

the code I use to load it is the same as in the geenrated files

```
MYWS adamStub = null;
        debugOut("WebserviceUrl = " +this.options.get("webServiceWsdlLocation"));
        if(this.options.get("webServiceWsdlLocation") != null) {
            URL wsdlUrl = getWsdlUrl();
            debugOut("got wsdl Url " + wsdlUrl.getPath());
            new MYWS (wsdlUrl, new QName(QNAME_WEBSERVICES, IADAM_L));
        } else {
            adamStub = new MYWS ();
        }
```

and the get wsdl method

```
private URL getWsdlUrl() {
        URL wsdlUrl = null;
        try {
            wsdlUrl = adam.xxxxxxx.class.getResource(
                    (String)this.options.get("webServiceWsdlLocation"));
            if(wsdlUrl == null)
                throw new MalformedURLException((String)this.options.get("webServiceWsdlLocation")+ 
                        " does not exist in the module.");
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return wsdlUrl;
    }
```

I thought that this would have been the best way to do it for different environments but it cant seem to load the wsdl correctly. The get wsdl code is taken directly from the generated class and the line below works fine

```
adamStub = new MYWS ();
```

All suggestions are appreciated. I dont want to regenerate the client for each environment or from my build.

UPDATE:

Made a proper schoolboy error here forgot to do the assignment

```
new MYWS (wsdlUrl, new QName(QNAME_WEBSERVICES, IADAM_L));
```

Comment: Is this a jax-ws web service client?

Comment: What exactly throws the `NullPointerException`? Have you checked that your custome properties are loaded properly (have you inspected it right before you use it)?

Comment: Yes this is a jax ws client. The Webservice client throws the null pointer. Yes the custom properties re loaded properly because this is the value in the custom properties which is printed out /META-INF/wsdl/my-pre.wsdl

Comment: please see update for answer